# What is the correct way of Multiple inheritance in Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, multiple-databases

In my Qt application, I have a base class as follow. I am using `QObject` because I want to use Signal-Slot mechanism in all derived classes.

```
class IRzPlugin : public QObject {

public:
  virtual void registerMenu(QWidget*);
  virtual void execute();
}
```

Then I have another class as follow. I need to extend from `QWidget` because I need to implement event handling methods in all derived classes (such as `mouseMoveEvent()`, `keyPressEvent()` and others).

```
class IRzLayeringPlugin : public IRzPlugin , public QWidget{

}
```

But compiler gives these the errors:

```
C:\svn\osaka3d\tags\iter08\prototype\osaka3d\rinzo\plugin\moc_IRzLayeringPlugin.cxx: In member function `virtual const QMetaObject* IRzLayeringPlugin::metaObject() const':
C:\svn\osaka3d\tags\iter08\prototype\osaka3d\rinzo\plugin\moc_IRzLayeringPlugin.cxx:51: error: `QObject' is an ambiguous base of `IRzLayeringPlugin'
C:\svn\osaka3d\tags\iter08\prototype\osaka3d\rinzo\plugin\moc_IRzLayeringPlugin.cxx:51: error: `QObject' is an ambiguous base of `IRzLayeringPlugin'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Rinzo.dir/plugin/moc_IRzLayeringPlugin.cxx.obj] Error 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the current incarnation, it isn't possible to use `QObject` in multiple inheritance paths for a derived class (like your `IRzLayeringPlugin` class).  The only solution I've ever seen was to create an interface class without any `QObject` inheritence, but with functions that directly correspond to the `QObject` functions you want to use, then implement the bridge between the interface and your other `QObject` class inheritance in your specific class.  It gets ugly fairly quickly.

Answer (score 8):

There was a similar question today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726716/qt-abstract-classes-and-objectcast/3726868#3726868).

Basically, two things are needed:

- Adding `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` after the interface class declaration
- Adding the interface to the `Q_INTERFACES` macro of the class

After this, qobject_cast will work with your interfaces.

If you'd like to use signals and slots from the interfaces, you are out of luck, because you can only do that with types that derive from QObject. But in this case, you would always get the `'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'IRzLayeringPlugin'` error.

In this case, @Caleb's idea is still the best.