# Qt interfaces or abstract classes and qobject_cast()

Tags: c++, qt, interface, qt4, qobject

I have a fairly complex set of C++ classes that are re-written from Java. So each class has a single inherited class, and then it also implements one or more abstract classes (or interfaces).

Is it possible to use `qobject_cast()` to convert from a class to one of the interfaces? If I derive all interfaces from `QObject`, I get an error due to ambiguous `QObject` references. If however, I only have the base class inherited from `QObject`, I can't use `qobject_cast()` because that operates with `QObject`s.

I'd like to be able to throw around classes between plugins and DLLs referred to by their interfaces.

Comment: As I'm reading more into the docs, I'm not sure what I want to do is possible...and that's not good. I could use the RTTI based .dynamicCast<T>() but it doesn't sound like that would always work across DLL boundaries.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201273/qt-moh-multiple-inheritance-problem so I guess it's already been asked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After some research and reading [the qobject_cast documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#qobject_cast), I found this:

> qobject_cast() can also be used in
>   conjunction with interfaces; see the
>   Plug & Paint example for details.

Here is the link to the example: [Plug & Paint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/tools-plugandpaint.html).

After digging up the [interfaces header](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/tools-plugandpaint-interfaces-h.html) in the example, I found the [Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtplugin.html#Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE) macro that should let you do what you want.

First, **do not** inherit `QObject` from your interfaces. For every interface you have, use the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE declaration like this:

```
class YourInterface
{
public:
    virtual void someAbstractMethod() = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(YourInterface, "Timothy.YourInterface/1.0")
```

Then in your class definition, use the [Q_INTERFACES](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#Q_INTERFACES) macro, like this:

```
class YourClass: public QObject, public YourInterface, public OtherInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(YourInterface OtherInterface)

public:
    YourClass();

    //...
};
```

After all this trouble, the following code works:

```
YourClass *c = new YourClass();
YourInterface *i = qobject_cast<YourInterface*>(c);
if (i != NULL)
{
    // Yes, c inherits YourInterface
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Cool. I had tried the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE, but didn't add the Q_INTERFACES to the derived object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Timothy - I'm happy I could help. I learn something new about Qt every day. :)

Comment: Normally, people use `if (YourInterface *i = qobject_cast<YourInterface*>(c)) { }`. This ensures that the pointer is never used if it is invalid.

Comment: @DeadMG - Good point, but I don't think putting `=` into an `if` statement is a good practice, because many people confuse it with `==`.

Comment: actually I've seen the pattern above used very commonly. Simply because people don't know the difference between = and == is not a good reason to use or not use it. Just like there's no reason to not use ++i vs i++ simply because they could be confused.

Comment: @Timothy - If you like it, use it. :)

Comment: @Venemo, What about casting upward? YourInterface *i = new YourClass(); YourClass *c = qobject_cast<YourClass*>(i); // qobject_cast fails, but with static_cast it works. Should static_cast be used in this case?

Comment: @krdx Are you sure that your interface has `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` and that your class inherits from `QObject` and lists your interface in `Q_INTERFACES`?

Comment: @Venemo yes. http://pastebin.com/Uwy6AKwB here's my example code. I am porting some C# code to C++(Qt) and I have trouble representing classes that implement (multiple) interfaces.

Comment: @Venemo I am trying to model something like this from C#: http://pastebin.com/kF8iPapm (some interface containing methods, and an event, this interface is implemented by an abstract base class, later I have many classes deriving from that abstract base class and finally a factory class.) Of course in this situation, when I have a single interface in C#, on the C++ side I could directly inherit a QObject for the interface and be done with it (IFoo : public QObject), although once I get into implementing many interfaces I will run into trouble.

Comment: @krdx No, your interfaces should definitely not inherit QObject.